# correct usage of token in href link text

Tags: entities, navigation, tokens

I have a content type with a text field and want to use that text field as the text in the href link in a block on that page. The block appears as a button and I want to use the text field as the text appearing in that button (which is a link).

The text field is rendered appropriately if I put it in the page, itself. However, I can't get the text into the href properly.

I have tried using [node:field-button-text] as well as [node:field_button_text] but neither is rendered.

I am not using a view and I would rather not have to code anything. Am I just using the wrong syntax or field identifier in my href

```
<a href="link stuff">[text identifier for a field on the page]</a>
```

or is there a deeper problem?

Thanks for any help

Comment: maybe check the token name at `admin/help/token`?

Comment: Thanks, I had checked the token name and there are two possibilities. Either one works in a link on the page (which might be how I end up handling this). Neither one works in a block on the page.

Comment: Oh right... yeah the block probably doesn't have access to node tokens at the time it is rendered.  Consider making a change to your node.tpl.php file or a new node-type.tpl.php file to achieve your desired result.